# How to accomplish Services.AddDbContext in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asp.net-core

I know how to add an in-memory database to an ASP.NET MVC Core app using .NET 6, in the Program.cs file like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyInMemoryDb");
});
```

Now I want to do the same thing, or similar, to a WPF app, also using .NET 6. I've tried searching for solutions to this problem, but I've not found anything. Even when I searched here on SO, the results are too far off to be useful. I'd appreciate direction, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried as below to accomplish the DI with IServiceCollection in a WPF App:

Packages:
[image]

App.xaml(dropped startupuri):

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             Startup="OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App :  Application
    {
        private ServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        public App()
        {
            ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(services);
            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
        private void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlite("Data Source = Some.db");
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
            });
            services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
        }
        private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWindow = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="categoryViewSource"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="categoryProductsViewSource"
                              Source="{Binding Products, Source={StaticResource categoryViewSource}}"/>
       
       
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="categoryDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryViewSource}}"
          Margin="13,13,43,229" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CategoryId}"
                            Header="Category Id" Width="SizeToHeader"
                            IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"
                            Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="productsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryProductsViewSource}}"
          Margin="13,205,43,108" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.251">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CategoryId}"
                            Header="Category Id" Width="SizeToHeader"
                            IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductId}" Header="Product Id"
                            Width="SizeToHeader" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,240,0,0"
        Click="Button_Click" Height="20" Width="123"/>

    </Grid>
   
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ProductContext _context;
        private CollectionViewSource categoryViewSource;
        public MainWindow(ProductContext context)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            _context = context;
            categoryViewSource =
                (CollectionViewSource)FindResource(nameof(categoryViewSource));
        }
       

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // load the entities into EF Core
            _context.Categories.Load();
            // bind to the source
            categoryViewSource.Source =
                _context.Categories.Local.ToObservableCollection();
           
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();

            // this forces the grid to refresh to latest values
            categoryDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
            productsDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Models and Dbcontext:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product>
            Products
        { get; private set; } =
            new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    }

    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {

        public ProductContext(DbContextOptions<ProductContext> opts):base(opts)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(new List<Product>() {
                new  Product(){ProductId=1,Name="p1",CategoryId=1},
                 new  Product(){ProductId=2,Name="p2",CategoryId=1},
                  new  Product(){ProductId=3,Name="p3",CategoryId=2}
            });
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(new List<Category>() {
                new  Category(){ Name="C1",CategoryId=1},
                 new  Category(){ Name="C2",CategoryId=2},
                 
            });
           
        }
    }
```

The result:
[image]

Based on the codes in  this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/wpf)

Comment: And thank you for pointing out that I'd left out DependencyInjection!

Comment: I wish I could select both answers as the solution, because each is excellent! However, SO only allows one. I'm choosing one at random, but I like both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

First thing on WPF you would need to get at least those packages installer

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

In your App.xaml.cs you can configure your ServiceProvider within overriding on StartUp method:

```
     public partial class App : Application
     {
            public static System.IServiceProvider? Container { get; private set; }
            protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
            {
                InitializeContainer();
                base.OnStartup(e);
            }
    
            private static void InitializeContainer()
            {
                ServiceCollection services = new();
                services.AddDbContext<TempContext>(e => e.UseInMemoryDatabase("dbNameInMemort"));
                Container = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            }
      }
```

as you can see its not so different as you do in ASP MVC

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I'd left out DependencyInjection!